# Single sign on with remote SSH server

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

Is it possible to authorize user based on provided login and password by connecting to remote SSH server?

If connection is successfully established and login-password pair is logged on the remote end, the user granted login access to the local machine.

I've heard that there is such PAM module, but now I can find only pam_ssh which manipulates (locally) on private keys.

Comment: What would be the use case for this? Just curious.

Comment: Look into Kerberos.

Comment: @gravity: simple domain login without extra infrastructure.

Comment: You would *still* have to manually add the user account to all servers, *and* it would become impossible to use SSH pubkey authentication if you required a password for the authorization checks (did you mean "authenticate" in your post?), and it would *still* require the same amount of "extra infrastructure" (one password-checking server) as Kerberos, but with more complicated and less standard configuration...

Comment: ...in conclusion, it would not be as simple as it looks.

Comment: @grawity, why should I add user accounts on every host? PAM modules can provide POSIX user information (UID, for example) there absolutely no need to  use local passwd/shadow files.

Comment: PAM cannot provide the complete information -- for example, any program that uses getpwnam() (which means 99.9% of them) will call **NSS** modules (`/etc/nsswitch.conf`). And every single module, other than `nss_files`, requires "extra infrastructure". Besides, if you want to use a "remote SSH server" for this, it's not even possible to retrieve the information reliably. Would you have to enter the SSH password every time a program requests your information?

Comment: I can't see any problem with nss - we can just add a new source like LDAP domains do. I don't know any other domain service which doesn't require anything except existing SSH login server. Reliability of remote server is determined by connectivity, security is provided by host keys and encryption. Information repeated retrieval is a big issue indeed, I've missed that point (in terms of SSH this is easily handled with ssh-agent though).